# SE Authentication server is down

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, authentication

It seems the SE Authentication server is down when visiting

http://stackauth.com/1.0/users/123456/associated

Comment: [Possibly related to Stack Exchange turning off v1 of the API yesterday?](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/api-v1-shutdown) Can you be a little more specific about how you arrived on at that page? Are you logging in to a site? Using a third party app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [announced previously](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/stack-exchange-api-v2-2-and-the-demise-of-v1-x/), the v1.x family of APIs has been shutdown ([after about 2 years of being deprecated](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/api-v1-shutdown)).

You should move to the [v2.x family](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).